# Multiple classes in one screen stops FloatLayout from working correctly

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to incorporate ads into a Kivy app I made, and to do this, I want to have one class (with the ads) in a FloatLayout to be at the top of my screen, and the rest of the app to be below, in a separate class.

I was trying to get this to work with some test code (simple .py and .kv file that has multiple screens and classes and organizes accordingly). The code is supposed to have two float layouts: One has text, the other has a button that you press and it takes you to the next screen. However the issue I am having is that I can't position the button correctly, as it appears that the widget is shrunk in the bottom left corner. It is supposed to be next to the text box.

Here is my .kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:

<Screen1>:
    name: "screen1"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            pos_hint: {'top': 1, "center_x": 0.5}
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.5)
            font_size: 40
            text: "TEXT AT TOP OF SCREEN"
    FloatLayout:
        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.05}
            size_hint: (0.3, 0.05)
            multline:False
    GoS:
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text: "PRESS TO GO TO SCREEN 2"
                pos_hint: {"right": 0.5, "center_y": 0.7}
                on_press: widget.goscreen()

<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"
    Label:
        text: "YOU ARE ON SCREEN TWO"
```

and here is the .py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class GoS(Widget):
    def goscreen(self):
        self.parent.current = "screen2"

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("rec_view.kv")

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Why is this happening?

Another small point also is that my button doesn't work because I can't seem to call the correct class. If I use "root.goscreen()", it doesn't work as my root widget doesn't have this function. What should be the correct syntax here?

Comment: Your `Screen1` class contains 3 children (2 `FloatLayouts` and a `GoS`). Each of those is the full size of `Screen1`, since the default `size_hint` is `(1,1)`. The `FloatLayout` inside `GoS` will be size `(100,100)`, since `GoS` is not a `Layout` and doesn't respect `size_hint`. It's not clear what you want your final gui to look like, but perhaps a better approach to attain a gui with a top, middle, and bottom section might be to use a `BoxLayout`. Also note that `FloatLayout` is the least restrictive `Layout`, so putting a `Label` inside a `FloatLayout` does not mean it will be drawn inside.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Feel free to add this as the answer and I can accept it :) I changed my class GoS from widget to FloatLayout and its fixed it. BoxLayouts still confuse me a little, but I know typically containers are better than floats. Just one more question, do you by any chance know what I should be calling to be able to call my GoS class (the very last point)?

Comment: If you add an `id` to your `GoS:` rule in `kv` (like: `id: gos`), then your `on_press` for the `Button` can be `on_press: gos.goscreen()`. And you can replace `self.parent.current = "screen2"` with `kv.current = "screen2"` in your `goscreen()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use `BoxLayout` to divide your GUI.

Your button don't work because you don't link it to a valid Widget.

The `GoS` widget must be define in KV or be imported.

Here is a proposition for your rec_view.kv file :

```
WindowManager:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:

<GoS>:
    Button:
        text: "PRESS TO GO TO SCREEN 2"
        on_press: root.goscreen()

<Screen1>:
    name: "screen1"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_y: 0.5   # Proportion of screen height that the widget occupe
            Label:
                font_size: 40
                text: "TEXT AT TOP OF SCREEN"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_y: 0.3
            TextInput:
                multline:False
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            GoS:

<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"
    Label:
        text: "YOU ARE ON SCREEN TWO"
```

The definition of `goscreen` is not correct, `GoS` is not a `Screen`, so his parent don't have `current` , use instead `App.get_running_app().root.current = "screen2"`.

I don't know what you want to do and why you define the `GoS` class, but you can avoid it. By moving the `goscreen` definition into `Screen1` class, and replace the 3rd `BoxLayout` of `Screen1` with this:

```
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint_y: 0.2
        Button:
            text: "PRESS TO GO TO SCREEN 2"
            on_press: root.goscreen()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your answer. The real reason why I was trying to do it this way was because I am trying to integrate ads into my app using KivyMob, and the documentation is showing me a separate class with a separate run command, so I am trying to figure out a way of combining it in my main code. I was hoping that by having a test code (like the one I did) would help me to see how merge the two bits of code together